# How can I increase the healthcheck timeout when launching an instance with Boxfuse?

Tags: cloudcaptain

My instance fails to come up within 60 seconds. How can I increase the timeout?

The error I'm getting both locally and on AWS is:

`ERROR: Time out: Payload of Instance vb-312f2f77 failed to come up within 60 seconds at http://127.0.0.1:8888/ !`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two available fixes /causes:

1. Increase the healthcheck timeout. For example to increase the
   default of 60 to 120 seconds you could use
   boxfuse fuse payload.war -healthcheck.timeout=120
   (More info: https://cloudcaptain.sh/docs/commandline/fuse.html#healthcheck.timeout)
2. Analyse the instance logs to check whether it is a genuine timeout
   or some application startup issue. You can do this by issuing
   boxfuse logs vb-312f2f77
   (More info: https://cloudcaptain.sh/docs/commandline/logs.html)

Comment: I just tried and although I set ```healthcheck.timeout=1200``` in the configfile and ```boxfuse -X``` prints ```15:33:32.091 healthcheck.timeout -> 1200``` on start, my application times out: ```15:46:59.993 ERROR: Deployment of ... failed in ...: Time out: ELB failed to put instances in service within 600 seconds```. Boxfuse didn't run for 1200 seconds, so it looks like the property is ignored?